# Append to Start of a file. Use MemoryBuffer or Stream writer and ReadAll Text

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio

I am creating and excel file with a few tabs on it. I create a StreamWriter bject and append excel XML to the file and all works fine.

However the issue I am having is that I need to put in a summary Tab at the start. In order to work out the summary I need to complete the other tabs and work out the records, rows and some stats and put on the summary tab.

The issue is, is that I cant append to the start of the file using Stream Writer. I did put in a place holder like a tag. Close the file and opened it again.. using ReadAllText and replacing the tag... then writing back to disk. Ok for small files but I am doing this over the network and the file is large so it looks like a double write when it happens and takes for ever.. well twice as long.

Is there a better way to do this. Should I use a memory buffer. Again I don't want to hog server resources. Speed is important here and the open and close and read all just isn't efficient.

Added some Code...

Straight forward code...

```
   //Open a temp File and use Stream Writer..

TempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
using (_reportWriter = new StreamWriter(TempFileName, true, Encoding.ASCII, 2048))
{
    WriteExcelXmlOpeningTags();

    WriteAllDataToFile();

    WriteWorksheetXmlClosingTags();
}

//Generate the Summary
String summary = GenerateReportSummary();

//Now I have to open the file, read all the bytes.. replace the tag with the summary and write all the data again...
```

.. This proc writes the opening tags in xml and a REPORTSUMMARYSHEET TagHolder to get replaced at the end.

```
    public void WriteExcelXmlOpeningTags()
    {
        _reportWriter.WriteLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");
        _reportWriter.WriteLine("<?mso-application Excel.Sheet?>");
        _reportWriter.WriteLine("<Workbook xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\" xmlns:ss=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\">");

        _reportWriter.WriteLine("<ss:Styles>");
        _reportWriter.WriteLine("<ss:Style ss:ID=\"StdHeaderStyle\">");
        _reportWriter.WriteLine("<ss:Font ss:Bold=\"1\"/>");
        _reportWriter.WriteLine("</ss:Style>");
        _reportWriter.WriteLine("<ss:Style ss:ID=\"StdRowStyle\">");
        _reportWriter.WriteLine("<Alignment ss:Vertical=\"Top\" ss:WrapText=\"1\"/>");
        _reportWriter.WriteLine("</ss:Style>");
        _reportWriter.WriteLine("</ss:Styles>");

        // This will be replaced with Report Summary Stats at the end of 
        _reportWriter.WriteLine("<REPORTSUMMARYSHEET_TAGHOLDER>");

        _reportWriter.Flush();

    }

    public void WriteWorksheetXmlClosingTags(int cols)
    {

        _reportWriter.WriteLine("</Table>");


        _reportWriter.WriteLine("<WorksheetOptions xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">" +
                  "<PageSetup>" +
                  "<Header x:Margin=\"0.3\"/>" +
                  "<Footer x:Margin=\"0.3\"/>" +
                  "<PageMargins x:Bottom=\"0.75\" x:Left=\"0.7\" x:Right=\"0.7\" x:Top=\"0.75\"/>" +
                  "</PageSetup>" +
                  "<Selected/>" +
                  "<FreezePanes/>" +
                    "<FrozenNoSplit/>" +
                    "<SplitHorizontal>1</SplitHorizontal>" +
                    "<TopRowBottomPane>1</TopRowBottomPane>" +
                    "<ActivePane>2</ActivePane>" +
                    "<Panes>" +
                    "<Pane>" +
                    "<Number>3</Number>" +
                    "</Pane>" +
                    "<Pane>" +
                    "<Number>2</Number>" +
                    "</Pane>" +
                    "</Panes>" +
                  "<ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>" +
                  "<ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>" +
                  "</WorksheetOptions>" +
                  "<AutoFilter x:Range=\"R1C1:R1C" + cols.ToString() +
                  "\" xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">" +
                  "</AutoFilter>");

        _reportWriter.WriteLine("</Worksheet>");
        _reportWriter.Flush();
    }
```

I then have to close the file.. and open it with FileReadAlltext and replace the tag. This is like a double effort as I have to incur the same time expensive the write all the bytes again with the short summery tag populated.

regards M

Comment: Have you considered using a library to build up the file in memory and write it to disk  rather than directly writing XML to a file?

Comment: There is not much code in your question to go on but I expect you missed the specific classes that exist to read and change xml documents, like XDocument. For working with OpenXML documents there is even a complete SDK. Use that instead of fiddling wit text replacements...

Comment: thank lads for the comments... the issue isn't the excel or how the file is generated... its how I have to close the file and open it again to add a summary to the start of the file. Yes maybe the excel api has a way to add in worksheets but I have to hand craft this file with xml as I cant install any excel libraries on the server unfortunately. So if I generate a file 100 mb in size I need to open it.. read it in.. add in the summary and write it all back out... double cost here

Comment: I didn't mention Excel... I said [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) and [OpenXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854(v=office.15).aspx) and your code confirms what I was suspecting...

Comment: What are you generating in the summary that can't be done before writing out data to the file? And in regards to Excel libraries, they do not need to be installed on the server as any library generating OpenXML is not using Office Interop. Can you ship any DLL's with your code?